# OCaml: Object definition & cloning

Tags: ocaml

```
class backup =
  object (self : 'mytype)
    val mutable copy = None
    method save = copy <- Some {< copy = None >}
    method restore = match copy with Some x -> x | None -> self
  end;;
```

In this piece of code, there are several things I do not quite understand.

1. (self: 'mytype) self means recursive class, but what is the role of 'mytype?
2. Some {} gets a backup copy where copy is still None, and assign it to copy?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

In C++, Java, and JavaScript the current object, the one executing the method, is always named `this`. In Smalltalk it's named `self`. In OCaml you can give it any name you like. Whatever name appears in parentheses after `object` is the name of the current object. In this example, the current object is named `self`. (I don't know what you mean by "recursive class.")

In some cases it's useful to have a name for the type of the current object. Again, you can give it any name you like by putting `: 'name` after the name of the current object. In this example, the type of the current object is named `'mytype`. The name isn't used anywhere in the code, but it might be used if the code were to get more complicated. Note that `'mytype` is not just another name for the class type `backup`. In a class that inherits from `backup`, `'mytype` represents the type of this inheriting class.

Your description of the `save` method seems right. It creates a copy of the current object and saves the copy in the field named `copy`. The copy's `copy` field is set to `None`. I.e., the copy doesn't have its own saved copy even if the containing object already had one. This method uses the special notation `{< ... >}`, which creates a copy of the current object.