# What does {< >} mean?

Tags: ocaml

The ocaml objects tutorial contains this piece of code, but does not explain it.

```
# class c0 = object method m = {< >} method n = 0 end;;
class c0 : object ('a) method m : 'a method n : int end
```

What does {< >} mean and where is it documented?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327654/ocaml-object-definition-cloning has your answer in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/OCaml.html has your answer in this site for each function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an informal definition of this construct in [Section 3.1.3 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/objectexamples.html#sec37). It says:

> The override construct {< ... >} returns a copy of “self” (that is, the current object), possibly changing the value of some instance variables.

A more formal definition is given in [Section 6.9.2](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/classes.html).

The expression `{< >}` contains no changes to instance variables, so it simply returns a copy of “self,” the current object.